# Specify Chrome as browser for running tests in

Tags: google-chrome, regression-testing, backstop.js

Trying to configure backstopjs to test page in Google Chrome instead of `phantomjs` as phantom doesn't render the page correctly.

Tried to replace

```
"engine": "phantomjs",
```

by

```
"engine": "chrome",
```

but it didn't help.

What should I install and how should I update config to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BackstopJS version 3 supports

> Render with Chrome Headless, Phantom and Slimer

So from now

```
"engine": "chrome",
```

will work if you have Chrome 61+ installed (or 59+ for Mac and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [differencify](https://github.com/NimaSoroush/differencify) which been built on top of Chrome headless